# How can I solved pdf-viewer download problem?

Tags: vaadin-flow

I would like to ask you a problem with the https://vaadin.com/directory/component/pdf-viewer in the directory. I want to display and save the byte as pdf. I am using version 1.0.2. They fixed this issue in version 2.7.2 https://github.com/vaadin-component-factory/vcf-pdf-viewer-flow/pull/29/commits/07fa83589e6a1a4ed94ad27a992bc470eb7ad294. What solution can I use version 1.0.2? I cannot use a dynamic streamResource that I created as new StreamResource(filename, () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(contents)) for the 2nd time. I will be grateful if you could help me. Thanks

I am using version 1.0.2. They fixed this issue in version 2.7.2 https://github.com/vaadin-component-factory/vcf-pdf-viewer-flow/pull/29/commits/07fa83589e6a1a4ed94ad27a992bc470eb7ad294. What solution can I use version 1.0.2? I cannot use a dynamic streamResource

Comment: If you have access to the 1.0.2 source, or you want to decompile/recompile it yourself then you may be able to update the 1.0.2 class to apply the same fixes as the 2.7.2 fix.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to version 1.0.2. source. I can't make the necessary bugFix